# Oracle 19c Default Values with Liquibase

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, liquibase, oracle19c

I have a quick question on why my default values are not being used.
Using oracle 19c, liquibase and spring-boot

```
<column name="ACTIVE" type="BOOLEAN" defaultValueBoolean="false">
  <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

With this being added successfully to the database and even showing in IntelliJ

```
ACTIVE NUMBER(1) = 0
```

Whenever I want to add a new entry to and do NOT set the active attribute I get

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
```

Adding:

```
MyEntity me = new MyEntity();
me.setSomething("Hi");
meRepository.save(me); // Error because I didn't use me.setActive(false);
```

I feel I am missing something obvious ...

(Same goes for other types such as LocalDatetime using type="TIMESTAMP" and defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out what's happening. For everyone wondering...

This project uses Hibernate (I didn't think about it) and it seems Hibernate sets all values to "null" when they are not manually set. And I didn't find a solution to add "default on null" in Liquibase.

That's I went for the solution of using the Hibernate Hook @PrePersist

```
class MyEntity {
  private Boolean attribute;

  @PrePersist
  public void onCreate() {
    if(attribute == null) attribute = DEFAULT_VALUE;
  }
}
```